# Lightweight binary image classifier

Tags: machine-learning, python, classification, image-classification

I want to build a fast binary classifier that decides if an image belongs to a given class (e.g. if it is a picture of a person). I want to do this by training a network on the RGB of pixels at a predetermined set of coordinates (e.g. 4 points, one near each corner of the image) and I want to achieve at least 75% accuracy.

How many points and what architecture should I use? Or if this is a very bad method what is another way to build a classifier that makes training and classification as fast as possible maybe on the account of lowering accuracy?

Comment: How many annotated images do you have? Why do you need the training to be very fast?

Comment: @JahKnows I want the training to be fast because I will have to annotate images myself.

Comment: Did I answer it?

Comment: @DavidMasip could you elaborate on how to find the pixels with Lasso?

Comment: Features in image classification are values of pixels. You can select the important features by using lasso (as always, lasso kills most of the features, so the ones that survive are the important ones), and those features are therefore the most important pixels. As Lasso has problems with correlated features, an elastic net very close to Lasso might be a better option.

Comment: @DavidMasip Thanks, but then the feature-finding wouldn't be really fast because I would have to run that on all pixels.

Comment: Nope, a Lasso is performed on the whole data, not once for every pixel.

Comment: And unless your computer is from the 1930s, performing a Lasso is lightning fast.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I wanted to build a classifier that takes short time to be trained, I would rather simplify the classifier than the data. In this case, I would rather train a logistic regression model (probably with Ridge or Lasso regularization), than a very complex architecture with few of the data I have.

If I had to simplify the data, I would take the average of the three channels, thus having a black and white image as input. I would not simplify it further (I am very confident that 4 points won't give decent accuracies).

I don't really know your circumstances, but Lasso in logistic regression is a method that might allow you to select some pixels. As the coefficients obtained by Lasso are sparse ([see this answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/151954/sparsity-in-lasso-and-advantage-over-ridge-statistical-learning)), Lasso will select the pixels that are relevant towards the prediction of the class. You can then train a bigger network with those pixels that allows you to capture nonlinearities and more complexity.